# Trying to identify Carlos Kleiber recording of Mozart/Beethoven with lots of applause at the end for funeral music

Tags: classical-music, beethoven, mozart

This question is about trying to identify a Carlos Kleiber recording of (probably) Mozart/Beethoven with lots of applause at the end for funeral music.

Recently a family member died who loved music and had a recording with Carlos Kleiber conducting, but we can't remember what it is. Most likely it is a Mozart/Beethoven symphony or possibly piano concerto. The distinctive thing about the recording is that there is lots of enthusiastic applause at the end.

The recording would be pre-1990 and could be pre 1980 and it was on vinyl.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this strange request. Any suggestions of possible recordings will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, think I have found the answer to this question so posting it here, but if anyone else finds another possiblity then I would be interested to hear it...

The recording may be Beethoven's 6th symphony, wfhich can be found [here.](http://hhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzMYaMk3R3w). There is about 5 minutes of applause at the end of this recording. Clearly the audience really liked it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Kleiber), Kleiber did not record much, but Beethovens symphony #7 (live recording from 1982) is among these. In my opinion the second movement from that might fit better for a funeral than anything from the more cheerful symphony #6.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason that I was looking for one with applause is that this is a recording the deceased played frequently, though your point is good about the mood.